# Exception while Twitter authentication in java

Tags: java, servlets, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to login with twitter using consumer key and secret. but when I login with twitter button, it throws following Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set.
twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterBaseImpl.java:281)
Twitter.TwitterSigninServlet.service(TwitterSigninServlet.java:35)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

This is my code in servlet

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
RequestToken requestToken;
request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(KEY, SECRET);          
requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken("http://127.0.0.1/userindexfb.jsp");            
String authURL = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
response.sendRedirect(authURL);
```

Is there any ways to solve this?

Comment: Have you researched this exception in the context of twitter? I see quite a few results in google.

Comment: No. Could you please give any idea on that?